# In which database table Magento Category page Meta Title is saved

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I want to update category page meta title in magento,

I have found magento meta description and keyword attribute value and table.

But not able to found category page meta title database table and attribute value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which table stored category meta tags (title, description, keywords)

Answer (score 1):

For meta title, description data are stored into catalog_product_entity_varchar table (EAV model). 
(not "catalog_product_entity_text" table because those fields are varchar not text)
In order to filter this table to show only those two fields, you can search by "attribute_id".

attribute_id could be find inside "eav_attribute" table, by searching "meta_title" on "attribute_code" field.

Will

Answer (score 0):

Category data saved in "`catalog_category_entity_*`" table. for example "`catalog_category_entity_text`"

As categories are part of catalog and catalog has follow the EAV model.
So in this table data saved with category attribute id and entity type id like varchar or text.